# Why it shows 403(forbidden) when making an ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I've made an ajax call with this:

```
$('.start-rate-fixed').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var videoRate = $('.start-rate input[name="rating"]:checked').val(),
            productId = parseInt($('.popover-content').prop('id'));
        $.ajax({
            url : ROOT + 'products/rate_video',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                'data[Product][id]' : productId,
                'data[Product][success_rate]' : videoRate
            }
        }).done(function(res){
            var data = $.parseJSON(res);
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

Where I defined ROOT as the webroot of my cakephp project in my default.ctp with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ROOT = '<?php echo $this->Html->url('/');?>';
</script>
```

and trying to retrieve data from a function "rate_video" defined in my products controller  but I get this error. Also I've tried a simple ajax for a test function but it showed me the same issue.

**Controller Code**

```
public function rate_video(){
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if($this->request->is('post') && $this->request->is('ajax')){
            $success_rate = $this->request->data['Product']['success_rate'];
            $this->Product->id = $this->request->data['Product']['id'];
            if($this->Product->saveField('success_rate', $success_rate)){
                echo json_encode('Successfully Rated');
            } else {
                echo json_encode('Error!!');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(ROOT);` when you call it before your ajax request?

Comment: Can you view the URL directly in your browser? What do you see?

Comment: Show please all headers, when your  ajax is processed

Comment: yes.. it shows localhost/dev.popover/products/rate_video (403 forbidden).. where dev.popover is my project name..

Comment: All headers Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:65
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:CAKEPHP=u120o8lov7c1rpeqn6206afuj6
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/dev.popover/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: What happens if you just go to this URL directly?

Comment: to go to direct URL nothing will happen coz there is a checking for post or ajax..

Comment: Is this a public action? When using Auth, make sure you use `$this->Auth->allow()` to whitelist this action as publically accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Please add dataType and a forward slash (/) at the end of your request URL

```
$.ajax({
        url : ROOT + 'products/rate_video/',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            'data[Product][id]' : productId,
            'data[Product][success_rate]' : videoRate
        },
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(res){
```

Comment: please have a look on the top.. :-)

Comment: Sorry, why didn't you include dataType on your ajax request? 403 error means that the server is denying your request.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and solved it by putting the URL within AJAX call to a URL that I know works. Then try accessing the URL that you are trying to invoke via AJAX directly within the web browser - most likely you are accessing a controller that does not have a view file created. To fix this you have to ensure that the controller method being accessed does not have a view to be rendered - set $this->render(null)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have incorrect url then

   ```
   url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Controllername', 'action' => 'actionname')); ?>'
   ```

   this above url provide ajax to url from root to your action.
2. And other cause for 403 is your auth function, if your using auth in your controller then make your ajax function allow like

   ```
   $this->Auth->allow('Your ajax function name here');
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Your script placed at `localhost/dev.popover/products/rate_video` but ajax ROOT is `/ -` that mean `localhost/` and ajax sent request to

```
'localhost/products/rate_video'
```

Right solution is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ROOT = '<?php echo $this->Html->url('/dev.popover/');?>';
</script>
```

Comment: If there an issues of changing the domain/project name the what will happen? Do I have to re-declare the ROOT again.. its not the perfect solution...

Comment: Try to define a constant at your project configuration file and use it whenever you need